# How to do Android layout wrap with contents?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

The contents of my android app are increasing from the layout portion, but I want to wrap the layout as contents are increasing.  Can I adjust my all contents on a single relative layout or is this possible on any other layout?

**Layout Code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ttl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ep"
        android:textColor="#00ccff"
        android:textSize="18sp" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"      
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/eprice" 
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:textColor="#BBB000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="@string/epval"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="245dp"
        />
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/molcal" 
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:textColor="#00cc00"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         />
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/molfac" 
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
        android:textColor="#BBB000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

         <EditText
        android:id="@+id/molex"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
        android:text="@string/molex"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        />

         <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/frght" 
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:textColor="#BBB000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

         <EditText
        android:id="@+id/frght"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
        android:text="@string/frghtport"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        />
          <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/whlfrg" 
        android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
        android:textColor="#BBB000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

         <EditText
        android:id="@+id/whar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="212dp"
        android:text="@string/whlfrgval"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        />

                <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/storage" 
        android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
        android:textColor="#BBB000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

         <EditText
        android:id="@+id/storage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="257dp"
        android:text="@string/storageval"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        />

         <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/expdev" 
        android:layout_marginTop="305dp"
        android:textColor="#BBB000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

         <EditText
        android:id="@+id/expdev"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="302dp"
        android:text="@string/expdeval"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        />

                <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clear" 
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:textColor="#BBB000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

         <EditText
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="347dp"
        android:text="@string/clearval"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        />
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/survey" 
        android:layout_marginTop="395dp"
        android:textColor="#BBB000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

         <EditText
        android:id="@+id/survey"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="392dp"
        android:text="@string/surveyval"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        />

          <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/transit" 
        android:layout_marginTop="440dp"
        android:textColor="#BBB000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

         <EditText
        android:id="@+id/transit"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="438dp"
        android:text="@string/transitval"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        />
               <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/total" 
        android:layout_marginTop="485dp"
        android:textColor="#BBB000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

         <EditText
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="483dp"
        android:text="@string/totval"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post your layout code.

Comment: if i am taking it right , you could try with scrollview instead of RelativeLayout .

Comment: @user1820339 Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Use below XML code instead of your code, it will solve your problem.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ttl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="ep"
            android:textColor="#00ccff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:text="eprice"
            android:textColor="#BBB000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ep"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="245dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="epval" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:text="molcal"
            android:textColor="#00cc00"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
            android:text="molfac"
            android:textColor="#BBB000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/molex"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="molex" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
            android:text="frght"
            android:textColor="#BBB000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/frght"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="frghtport" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
            android:text="whlfrg"
            android:textColor="#BBB000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/whar"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="212dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="whlfrgval" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
            android:text="storage"
            android:textColor="#BBB000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/storage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="257dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="storageval" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="305dp"
            android:text="expdev"
            android:textColor="#BBB000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/expdev"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="302dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="expdeval" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
            android:text="clear"
            android:textColor="#BBB000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="347dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="clearval" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="395dp"
            android:text="survey"
            android:textColor="#BBB000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/survey"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="392dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="surveyval" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="440dp"
            android:text="transit"
            android:textColor="#BBB000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/transit"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="438dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="transitval" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="485dp"
            android:text="total"
            android:textColor="#BBB000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/total"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="483dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="totval" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it is a good question. You can set the layout height and width to wrap content and if you need to add other things you can use the following tags:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
```

According to me, Relative Layout is the best to use over others.